# Pass Variables inside Screen Stuff

Tags: php, variables, shell-exec, gnu-screen

I have this code:

```
<?php
$say = $_GET['say'];
if ($_GET['run']) {
# This code will run if ?run=true is set.
$output = shell_exec("sudo -u root screen -S mine-a1 -X stuff '$say\015';    echo 'Feito'");
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form name='form' method='post' action="?run=true">
[/]: <input type="text" name="say" id="say" ><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
<?php print $output?>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to have a input box that receives a variable in text mode and get it inside stuff ''.

PS. If I don't use the variable `$say` inside the stuff quotes the script is working.

Answer (score 0):

$say = $_GET['say'];  <- Corrected to _POST obviously!

Answer (score 0):

if ($_GET['run']) //what it means?. 
use if(isset($_REQUEST['run'])). you can use $_POST or $_REQUEST.

```
<?php
$say = $_REQUEST['say'];
if (isset($_REQUEST['run']) and $_REQUEST['run']=='true'){
$output = shell_exec("sudo -u root screen -S mine-a1 -X stuff '$say\015';    echo 'Feito'");
}
?>
```